# Remove Member for rapid JSON nested objects

Tags: rapidjson

Are there examples to remove a member within a nested JSON object?

For example: Consider the below JSON snippet, how would I be able to remove member C from the rapid son library?

```
{
"a": 1,
"b":{"c" : 2, "d" : 3}
}
```

I am not looking for hardcoded removal.. Like a.RemoveMember("c"); I am looking for code examples to remove a member from a rapid JSON document using the member iterator.
All the examples I see are for ConstMemberIterator. But RemoveMember can only be called with Member Iterators

From the document https://rapidjson.org/md_doc_tutorial.html, I am looking for an examples code snippet for the following function:

```
MemberIterator RemoveMember(MemberIterator): Remove a member by iterator (constant time complexity).
MemberIterator EraseMember(MemberIterator): similar to the above but it preserves order of members (linear time complexity).
MemberIterator EraseMember(MemberIterator first, MemberIterator last): remove a range of members, preserves order (linear time complexity).
```

Comment: I don't know if this can resolve your issue or not (https://rapidjson.org/md_doc_pointer.html)

`// Erase a member or element, return true if the value exists`

`bool success = Pointer("/b/c").Erase(d);`

`assert(success);`

Comment: Thanks, in the same example, if I do bool success = Pointer("/b").Erase(d); will it work? @MohamedSaeed

Comment: Yes, but it will erase the entire `b`  object. The result will be `{"a": 1}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can resolve your issue or not
(http://rapidjson.org/md_doc_pointer.html)

```
// Erase a member or element, return true if the value exists 
bool success = Pointer("/b/c").Erase(d); 
assert(success);
```

#### Edited

Yes, but it will erase the entire `b` object. The result will be `{"a": 1}`